# How to use Multiple Cl-editor in Same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor, cleditor

i want to try display multiple Cl-editor for my texarea field in same page. but only one was working. others are disable. 
 my Code are below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cleditor/jquery.cleditor.css" />
<script src="cleditor/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="cleditor/jquery.cleditor.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#payscale").cleditor();
        $("#desc").cleditor();

    });
</script>
```

Html Code in Same Page :

```
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Pay Scale:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <textarea rows="3" cols="5" name="payscale" id="payscale" class="form-control"> </textarea>
</div>

<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <textarea rows="5" cols="5" name="desc" id="desc" class="form-control"> </textarea>
</div>
```

[image: Payscale : Disable]
[image: desc. : Anabel]